# Using loadFont() function to load *.ttf from directory

Tags: javascript, p5.js

I am having the following folder structure:

[image]

I am using the following `p5js` library:

```
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.7.2/p5.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.7.2/addons/p5.dom.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.7.2/addons/p5.sound.min.js"></script>
```

I am trying to load my font using the following:

```
let myFont;
function preload() {
  // var myFont = loadFont('Abel-Regular.ttf');
  myFont = loadFont("fonts/NotoSerifArmenian-Thin.ttf");
}
```

However I get as error:

```
Font could not be loaded fonts/NotoSerifArmenian-Thin.ttf
cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.7.2/p5.min.js:11
```

Any suggestions what I am doing wrong?

I appreciate your replies!

Comment: Are you running an HTTP server to serve the font? If you're running from the context of src, then the path would be wrong, so I assume you're running your server in the root project directory.

Comment: Not sure but probably, it should be `..fonts/NotoSerifArmenian-Thin.ttf`.

Comment: @herrstrietzel did you mean `../fonts/NotoSerifArmenian-Thin.ttf`?

Comment: I tried all of the above and still get: `Font could not be loade`

Comment: I am using the liveserver plugin from vscode to serve my html page